# Convert a JSON object into a set of custom object

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, objectmapper

I have a json object similar to the below one.

```
{
  "key1": {
    "code1": "name1",
    "code2": "name2",
    ...
  },
  "key2": {
    "code1": "name1",
    "code2": "name2",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I want to convert this json object into Map<String, Set< Key >> instead of Map<String, Map<String, String>> which I can do normally with ObjectMapper.

The Key class I want look something similar to this.

```
public class Key{
  private String code;
  private String Name;
}
```

I tried some custom deserializer with the help of chatgpt.

```
public static class KeyListDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Set<Key>> {

    @Override
    public Set<Key> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        Set<Key> keyList = new HashSet<>();
        JsonNode rootNode = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = rootNode.fields();
        while (fields.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
            String code = field.getKey();
            String name = field.getValue().asText();

            Key key = new Key();
            key.setCode(code);
            key.setName(name);

            keyList.add(key);
        }

        return keyList;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, throwing below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.HashSet<um.Test1$Key>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

I can deserialize it to Map<String, Map> and convert it to Map<String, Set< Key >> manually, but i thought it is better to achieve it through objectmapper itself instead of separate handling.

How can I directly deserialize the object into Set?

Comment: Use a custom deserialiser?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I updated the details of custom deserializer in the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

To directly deserialize your JSON object into a `Map<String, Set<Key>>` using Jackson's ObjectMapper, you can create a custom deserializer for your `Key` class and configure the ObjectMapper to use this custom deserializer when deserializing the JSON object. Here's how you can do it:

First, let's define your `Key` class with the appropriate getters and setters:

```java
public class Key {
    private String code;
    private String name;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, and any other methods
}
```

Next, create a custom deserializer for the `Key` class:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

import java.io.IOException;

public class KeyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Key> {
    @Override
    public Key deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        String code = node.fieldNames().next();
        String name = node.get(code).asText();
        return new Key(code, name);
    }
}
```

Now, configure your ObjectMapper to use the custom deserializer:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Register the custom deserializer for the Key class
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Key.class, new KeyDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        String json = "YOUR_JSON_STRING_HERE"; // Replace with your JSON data

        // Deserialize the JSON into a Map<String, Set<Key>>
        Map<String, Set<Key>> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Set<Key>>>() {});

        // Now you have the desired Map<String, Set<Key>>
    }
}
```

Replace `"YOUR_JSON_STRING_HERE"` with your actual JSON data. This code should correctly deserialize your JSON object into a `Map<String, Set<Key>>` using the custom deserializer for the `Key` class.

Comment: Receiving this error:
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.HashSet<um.Test1$Key>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

This is the json I used:
{
  "key1": {
    "code1": "name1",
    "code2": "name2"
  },
  "key2": {
    "code3": "name3",
    "code4": "name4"
  }
}